# How to start Sybase server

Tags: linux, installation, sybase-ase

I have installed Sybase(Developer's Edition for ASE 16.0) on a linux machine. I have executed the setup.bin file, and installed it using GUI. After this, I tried connecting to the *localhost* server, by running the *dbisql* executable in the *DBISQL-16_0/bin* folder of the base-installation-folder but couldn't connect to the '*localhost:5000*' server, using the username/password of the server. I am not sure if the server is tarted. Do I need to run anything to start the server, or perform any other actions before trying to connect using this client?

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Contact Sybase for support issues running their server. This site is for programming related questions. Sybase has it's own forums.

Comment: @Michael: Possibly; I'm not sure it fits in the guidelines there. No matter, though; it's not on-topic here. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Following information was found on [sybasewiki](http://sybaseblog.com/sybasewiki/index.php?title=How_can_we_start_the_sybase_server%3F) Hope this helps !

How to start the sybase server?

After log in your Linux/Unix machine.

```
Step 1:  Find out current location or present working directory.
Step 2:  Locate environmental file SYBASE.sh or SYBASE.csh profile which is ,by default, located in $SYBASE.
Step 3:  Run environmental file.
Step 4:  Verify SYBASE.sh or SYBASE.csh run properly.
Step 5:  Find out RUN_Serverfile
Step 6:  Start server with startserver.
Step 7:  Start backup server with startserver.
```

---

```
Step 1: pwd   -- know your present working directory.
Step 2: cd  <directory_name_where_SYBASE.sh_present> --find out SYBASE.sh profile which can you find SYBASE ASE directory.
Step 3: . SYBASE.sh   -- run it and include it.
Step 4: echo $SYBABE  -- shows path where $SYBASE created which verify that SYBASE.sh run prperly.
Step 5: cd $SYBASE/SYBASE_ASE/install 
        ls -ltr  -- find out RUN_server_file name.
Step 6: startserver -f RUN_servername

Starting Back Up Server :
 Step 7:startserver -f RUN_SYB_BACKUP
```

Note: **depends upon installation where SYBASE ASE Server installed, so relative path of Run_serverfile can be differ.**